# What information can insurance companies share with brokers?

Tags: gdpr

I'm currently in the process of buying my first home, and have a mortgage broker helping me through the process. Our broker found us life insurance (to cover the cost of the mortgage) through a large insurance company in the UK.

We completed the questionnaire and we're accepted for a premium, but unfortunately we were stuck in a chain and therefore had to renew our quote and complete the questionnaire again.

On round 2, there was a discrepancy in my data and I was refused cover from the insurance company. My mortgage broker called the company and asked them why this was. He was given full details of my survey, including my responses to some very sensitive information regarding my past health.

I feel like the insurance company over shared information, but I'm not sure what the view from the law is on this.

I've reached out to the company and logged a complaint, but I want to understand if from the perspective of the law anything has been breached?

Comment: Was the sensitive information relevant to the refusal of cover? To what extent did you authorise your mortgage broker to help you with insurance? Could the insurance company have mistaken your broker for you? Have you tried the ICO live chat or helpline?  https://ico.org.uk/make-a-complaint/